# Setting and using variables with "bash -c"

Tags: linux, bash

Simple question ... why doesn't something like this work?

```
/bin/bash -c "b=4; echo $b"
```

The output is just blank space.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables between double quotes are expanded before the command is
run. Use single quotes:

```
/bin/bash -c 'b=4; echo $b'
```

Comment: I myself struggled with this long, long time ago - thanks;  this was elegant.

Comment: shoot me now...

Comment: thank you Arkadiusz Drabczyk